# Radio button value not inserting into database

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, radio-button

I have a problem with my radio button value that doesn't get inserted into the database. I'm using ajax so in my PHP file I request for the values and one of them is the radio button that is selected.

In my external javascript file, the variable "gender" is assigned correctly according to the selected radio button. However, the query executed in the PHP file does not insert the radio button's value into the database at all. The rest of the values do get inserted except the radio button which appears as blank once the table is displayed.

Note: I'm not using a form.

These are the codes from my PHP file:

```
                               .
                               .
                            Some other codes
                               .
                               .

function insertRow($name, $address, $phone, $gender, $nation){
    $table_info = "info";
    $query_string = "insert into $table_info(name, address, phone, gender, nation) values('$name', '$address', '$phone', '$gender', '$nation');";
    $result = @mysql_query($query_string) or die (mysql_error());
  }
?>

<?php
 if(isset($_REQUEST['id'])){
   $id  = rtrim($_REQUEST['id']);
 }
 if(isset($_REQUEST['name'])){
$name = $_REQUEST['name'];
 }
 if(isset($_REQUEST['address'])){
  $address = $_REQUEST['address'];
 }
 if(isset($_REQUEST['phone'])){
  $phone = $_REQUEST['phone'];
 }
 if(isset($_REQUEST['gender'])){
  $gender = $_REQUEST['gender'];
 }
 if(isset($_REQUEST['nation'])){
  $nation = $_REQUEST['nation'];
 }
$action = rtrim($_REQUEST['action']);

if($action=="delete"){
 echo deleteRow($id);
 echo update_database();
}
elseif($action=="insert"){
 echo insertRow($name, $address, $phone, $gender, $nation);
 echo update_database();
 }
   else{
    echo update_database();
  }
?>
```

These are the codes from my javascript file:

```
                           .
                           . 
                      Some other functions
                           .
                           .

 function insertThis(){
  var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
  var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
  var phone = document.getElementById("phone").value;
  var gender;
  var radioButtons = document.getElementsByName("gender");
  var nation = document.getElementById("nation").value;

  var page = "database.php";

  for(var i=0, length=radioButtons.length; i<length; i++){
  if(radioButtons[i].checked){
    gender = radioButtons[i].value;
   break;
  }
 }

  var parameters = "name="+name+"&address="+address+"&phone="+phone+"&gender="+gender+"&nation="+nation+"&action=insert";

  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

  if(xmlhttp==null){
   alert("Your browser does not support ajax!");
   return false;
  }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
    document.getElementById("divTable").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
 };
  xmlhttp.open("GET", page+"?"+parameters, true);
  xmlhttp.send(null);
}
```

And lastly, the radio buttons that are in the HTML file:

```
  <td>Gender:</td>
    <td><input checked type="radio"  name="gender" id="male"  value="Male">Male
   <input type="radio" name="gender" id="female"  value="Female">Female</td>
```

Comment: what is the datatype for your `gender` column? have you tried printing out your `$query_string` to see if your `$gender` is correct in your query?

Comment: Datatype for gender is varchar(6), how do I print out my $query_string though, echo it in the function?

Comment: Not entirely sure, but try either `&radioButtons="+gender` or `&gender="+radioButtons`. Since you've already declared `radioButtons` in `var radioButtons = document.getElementsByName("gender");`

Comment: @Fred-ii- `var radioButtons` is use later in `for(var i=0, length=radioButtons.length; i<length; i++){` to set `if(radioButtons[i].checked){ gender = radioButtons[i].value; break;}`. so `&gender="+gender` should be fine.

Comment: If every value is inserting, except for `gender`, then either `$gender` in your query is blank, which you would see if you did `echo $query_string;` or it is an invalid value, which is unlikely with `varchar(6)`

Comment: @Sean Where do I try out `echo $query_string;` though, in the function itself?

Comment: yes, you would need to either echo in the function, or you could use `return  $query_string;` in the function and then when do `echo insertRow($name, $address, $phone, $gender, $nation);` it will echo the query string.

Comment: If it's a db-related error, remove the `@` in `$result = @mysql_query` you may be suppressing possible errors.

Comment: Fixed it, it's Vikas' answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your code like this.

Replace:

```
for(var i=0; length=radioButtons.length; i<length; i++)
```

with:

```
for(var i=0; i< radioButtons.length; i++)
```

Rewrite:

```
for(var i=0; i< radioButtons.length; i++){
  if(radioButtons[i].checked){
    gender = radioButtons[i].value;
   break;
  }
 }
```

Comment: OP has `var radioButtons = document.getElementsByName("gender"); for(var i=0, length=radioButtons.length; i<length; i++){ if(radioButtons[i].checked){ gender = radioButtons[i].value; break; } }`. So how is your code different from that?

Comment: @Sean is right, it's the same as what I coded but just a shorter version.

Comment: @Vikas-Umrao I assumed it wouldn't work at first, but this seems to be the solution as when I tried your answer out, it displays.

Comment: I'd appreciate if you or anyone could explain to me why though, otherwise thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To help diagnose, modify `insertRow()` to either `echo $query_string;` and `print_r($_REQUEST);`, or write them to a file, or email them to yourself.

This will write to a file, then you can open it and look at what might be happening:

```
file_put_contents($query_string . "\n\n" . print_r($_REQUEST, true), 'test_file.txt');
```

Tip: you should consider protecting your code against SQL injection and incorrect values, because unexpected data could be supplied to database.php. For example, turn `if(isset($_REQUEST['gender']))` into `if (isset($_REQUEST['gender']) and in_array($_REQUEST['gender'], array('Male', 'Female')))`